# The isomorphisms between $S^5$ and $SU(3)/SU(2)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

What is the precise isomorphisms between the coset $SU(3)/SU(2)$ and the five-sphere $S^5$?

Comment: I can't claim any expertise on this, and it may have been decades since last I looked at such things, but $SU(3)$ acts on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^3$ (i.e., on $S^5$), and a copy of $SU(2)$ would be the stabilizer of $(0,0,1)$, say. From these facts, you should be able to piece together an isomorphism.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $S^5$ is not parallelizable, so I don't think it's a Lie group.

Answer (score 3):

The word "isomorphism" is not really appropriate here, because $SU(3)/SU(2)$ doesn't inherit any algebraic structure (in particular, it's not a Lie group). But there's a *diffeomorphism* $\phi\colon SU(3)/SU(2)\to S^5$, constructed as follows.

Let $p_0=(0,0,1)$ be the "north pole" in $S^5\subseteq \mathbb C^3$.  The isotropy group of $p_0$ in $SU(3)$ is $SU(2)$, identified with the following block-diagonal subgroup of $SU(3)$:
$$
\left\{
\left(
\begin{matrix}
A & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right):
A\in SU(2)
\right\}
$$

Define a map $\Phi\colon SU(3)\to S^5$ by $\Phi(g) = g\cdot p_0$. This is constant on left cosets of $SU(2)$, so it descends to the quotient to yield a map $\phi\colon SU(3)/SU(2)\to S^5$, which sends the coset $g\cdot SU(2)$ to the point $g\cdot p_0$. The fact that this is a diffeomorphism follows from the standard theory of quotient manifolds. (See my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, 2nd ed., Chapter 21.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was also wondering: what would happen if you considered the conjugate action, $h\cdot g\cdot h^{-1}$ where $h\in SU(2)$ and $g\in SU(3)$, instead of the left multiplication?

Comment: That's not a free action (for example, the identity of $SU(3)$ is fixed by all of $SU(2)$), so the quotient won't be a manifold.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused about a excerpt from the wiki page about n-spheres (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere):
"5-sphere:
Principal U(1)-bundle over CP2. SO(6)/SO(5) = SU(3)/SU(2)."
Since $SO(6)/SO(5) = S^5$, can't I indentify $SU(3)/SU(2)$ also with the 5-sphere?

Comment: Not exactly "identify."  My answer showed that $SU(3)/SU(2)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^5$; but the diffeomorphism depends on a choice of the point $p_0$. Those "=" signs are misleading -- they're really just diffeomorphisms.